# How to make encode and decode functions as I want?

Tags: lua, decode, encode, bytecode, lua-table

```
--encode
function strToBytes(str)
 local bytes = { str:byte(1, -1)
 for i = 1, #bytes do
  bytes[i] = bytes[i] + 100
 end
 return table.concat(bytes, ',')
 end

--decode
function bytesToStr(str)
 local function gsub(c)return string.char(c - 100) end
 return str:gsub('(%d+),?', gsub) end
```

implemented :

```
str = "hello world"

strbyte = strToBytes(str)

bytestr = bytesToStr(strbyte)

print(strbyte)
```

Output :

> 204,201,208,208,211,132,219,211,214,208,200

print(bytestr)
Output :

> "Hello world"

Hi, I need improving my code above. Actually encode and decode functions is work fine, but I need a little bit change.

I want to make encode functions similar like code above, but, the results is table like below :

> {204,201,208,208,211,132,219,211,214,208,200}

Then, same as like my first decode functions, all bytes inside the table should be back to "hello world".

I hope my purpose and explanation above is easy to understand. Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Update explanation :

It is a little bit complicated to explain what is my purposes. But I will try to explain as good as I can.

I am trying to make scripts encoder. Encode functions is in encoder scripts side, and decode function is in encoded scripts side. So I must write concatenate decode function before encoded string.

To clearly my explanation, encoder scripts will load undecode source code.

```
file = io.open(path, "r")
local data = file:read("*l")
```

The problem is, table cant concatenate with string.

```
local data = encode(str)--the result is byte array
local data = "decode("..data..")"
file:write(data)
file:close()

local data = string.dump(load(data),true,true)
```

My first purpose is to hide some important string, because string.dump result is not hide all string.
My second purpose is, to make an obsfucated code using byteArray.

Any solution or suggestion?

**SOLVED**

```
function strToBytes(str)
  local byteArray= { str:byte(1, -1) }
  for i = 1, #byteArray do
  byteArray[i] = byteArray[i] + 100
  encoded = '{' ..table.concat(byteArray, ',') .. '}'
end
  return "load(string.dump(load(bytesToStr("..encoded.."))))()\n"
end
```

Thank you so much...

Comment: why dont you just return `'{'.. table.concat(bytes, ',') .. '}'` from encode?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was very close to what you were looking for.

```
--encode
function strToBytes(str)
    local byteArray= { str:byte(1, -1) }
    for i = 1, #byteArray do
        byteArray[i] = byteArray[i] + 100
    end
    return '{' .. table.concat(byteArray, ',') .. '}'
 end
```

For the encode I removed the table.concat and now just return the byteArray

```
--decode
function bytesToStr(byteArray)
    local output = ""                              --initialize output variable
    for _,b in ipairs(byteArray) do                --use ipairs to preserve order
        output = output .. string.char(b - 100)    --convert each byte to a char and add to output
    end
    return output
end
```

For the decode I use a for loop with `ipairs` to iterate over each byte and concatenate the values into an output variable.

```
-- test
str = "hello world!"

strbyte = strToBytes(str)
bytestr = 'return bytesToStr(' .. strbyte .. ')'
strBack = string.dump(load(bytestr),true,true)

print(strbyte)
print(bytestr)
print(load(strBack)())
```

Test output:

> {204,201,208,208,211,132,219,211,214,208,200,133}
>
> return bytesToStr({204,201,208,208,211,132,219,211,214,208,200,133})
>
> hello world!

Comment: Encode and decode works. But, in my case, encode and decode functions is not in the same file. local data = strToBytes(data) local data = "bytesToStr("..data..")"  file:write(data)

Comment: @RedStarksten I do not understand, why are you doing ` local data = "bytesToStr("..data..")" file:write(data)`? can you clarify by editing your question.